# C# application keeps freezing on remote

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, remote-desktop

I am developing a C# application (.Net 3.5, Win Forms) which is run on a server, and is accessed by Users using remote desktop. The application keeps freezing on seemingly random occasions on the remote machine (i.e. all GUI components turn to white, task manager reports the application to be not responding), but not when run locally (I'm not *entirely* sure about that, but failed to reproduce the freeze on my machine).

Has anyone experienced such behavior in his apps that are accessed remotely? What debugging strategy would you suggest? Do I need to consider something special when developing Win Forms applications that are accessed by remote desktop?

EDIT: some notes about the application and the freeze: The application does not recover from the freeze. Also, the freeze does not happen (or did not happen yet) during user interaction, but in between log ins to the remote machine. The application monitors a CFD solver, so it's doing things even when no one is using it.

**UPDATE:**

We did infact implement detailed logging, writing every function call to a file with a timestamp. Unfortunately, the results were not very conclusive. I.e. the last function call logged always returned correctly. Also, there were some background timers still running, even though the application appeared frozne (GUI completely white etc.). After [some trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818679/windbg-application-hang-wrong-symbols) we managed to have a look at a crashdump in WinDBG. On the system thread we found a call to OnUserPreferenceChanged() and further up to Invoke.WaitOne(). We can't say for sure yet, but it seems to be the issue decribed in [these](http://www.ikriv.com/en/prog/info/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html) [articles](http://krgreenlee.blogspot.com/2007/09/onuserpreferencechanged-hang.html). As a quick fix, I installed a dummy handler to the event mentioned. I'll report how this works out.

**UPDATE 2:**

As it turns out, a Log In to a remote machine fires several OnUserPreferenceChanged() events. So it was indeed the suspected issue. The fix turned out to be not so easy though. I would have expected that an IllegalCrossReferenceException is thrown everytime a background thread tries to modify a control that was created on the system thread. This does not seem to be the case. I named my system thread and before each access to a control I asserted that the current thread name is the system thread's name. In various places this assertion failed (e.g. in a callback from a timer), but no exception was thrown. After using proper delegation at these places, the freezes stopped. The application runs nonstop for some weeks now and my users are happy again ;)

Comment: Cross-reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077822/net-4-0-and-the-dreaded-onuserpreferencechanged-hang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think the freeze has anything to do with remote desktop.  Adding logging was a good suggestion.  I have a few suggestions, but without knowing the details of you application I can't get too specific.

The simplest suggestion I have is to check the memory useage and CPU usage in task manager when the freeze occurs.

If adding detailed logging is not an option, add just enough logging to know WHEN the application freezes.  This could simply be a thread in the application which writes a timestamp to a file once a minute.  Then you can see if there is any pattern in when it freezes, such as after a user has logged off, or when some of the data which you are monitoring changes, or at a certain time each day, or after being online for a certain amount of time.

A final and very hacky solution is to write a small watch dog application.  This application's only job is to periodically check on the main application to make sure it is still responsive.  How you dow this various drastically based on what your application does.  If the watchdog sees the the main application has stopped, it can kill the thread for the main application and re-start it from the binaries.

Comment: WinDBG is a great tool.  I should have put that in my answer!  Thanks for the upvote, that's my first one. :)

Comment: Why Marked as Correct: "As it turns out, a Log In to a remote machine fires several OnUserPreferenceChanged() events. So it was indeed the suspected issue. " Means the first line of this Answer makes it wrong? "I do not think the freeze has anything to do with remote desktop."

Answer (score 1):

if your using application streaming your server could be slowing the connection or waiting for packets that are dropping this can create this if your physical using windows remote desktop then there is your problem intense applications are not supposed to be run though remote desktop

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no difference. Additionaly, I never experienced such a problem. I suggest, you try the following:

- Extend your application with extended logging, to see what the users are doing when your application freezes
- Check the network connection that is used to connect to the remote machine
- Check the CPU usage during the freeze

If the freeze is for an extended amount of time, try to do the following:

- Reproduce the freeze via remote desktop.
- Go to the machine you just reproduced the freeze on and log in directly and see, whether the application is still freezed

Comment: Thanks for the Input so far. To add extended logging is kind of a labor intensive undertaking (~30'000 loc), but we'll resort to that if no other options are left. Unfortunately, the Bug does not happen (or did not happen yet) during user interaction, users only seem to encounter the application frozen when they log into the remote server (the app is mainly for monitoring some things). The application does not recover from the freeze. However, I will definitely log in to the machine directly the next time the freeze occurs, good point!

Comment: Sure, adding logging is always a pain in the ass, if you need to do it afterwards. Maybe you can somehow narrow it down to a certain part of the code.

Comment: There seems to be no reason for the freeze to have anything to do with the remote desktop, as the freeze happens, when there is no one connected...

Answer (score 0):

If it is windows 10 version 1903 plus version. Then probably its the issue of windows. Please try the following settings:
 Have read various blogs and concluded that the GPO has to force to use XDDM rather than WDDM. The issue is observed with windows 10 version 1903. Currently tested the workaround on machine NDT-61. It is working fine. Please practice the same for respective environment and let me know if some issue is faced.

Steps to Follow:

1. Open Group Policy Editor
2. Explore Administrative Templates
3. Explore Windows Components
4. Explore Remote Desktop Service
5. Click Remote Session Environment
6. Under Remote Session Environment Disable Use WDDM graphics display drive for Remote Desktop Connections

Note:

This policy setting lets you enable WDDM graphics display driver for Remote Desktop Connections.
If you enable or do not configure this policy setting, Remote Desktop Connections will use WDDM graphics display driver.
If you disable this policy setting, Remote Desktop Connections will NOT use WDDM graphics display driver. In this case, the Remote Desktop Connections will use XDDM graphics display driver.

For this change to take effect, you must restart Windows

Observation:

The policy settings are only available in windows 10 version 1903 and plus [ideally since when the issue started].