# What causes SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged to be invoked?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have come across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077822/net-4-0-and-the-dreaded-onuserpreferencechanged-hang) on this site that mentions the possibility of UI hanging when the `SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged` event is fired. Now, I have not experienced this in my application, but I would like to test whether this bug might be lurking undetected in my code until it is too late.

However, despite doing some searching, I cannot seem to find 
comprehensive documentation regarding *what causes* the `SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged` event to be fired.

What are some (all?) system events that cause it to be fired? Is it just a wrapper for the [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx) message, or is there more to the story? What settings can I change to cause it to be fired?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: By most common reason for the deadlock it causes is a switch to the secure desktop.  Press the Win+L keys.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov the link you provide is indeed the SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged Event documentation, but that documentation lacks any examples of what causes the event to be invoked. Hence I too had to search, and found the answer here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.userpreferencecategory(v=vs.110).aspx). **UserPreferenceChanged** Event may occur when one of the Events in the below categories are triggered!. This is for a class of type [UserPreferenceChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.userpreferencechangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). I think the Description is self explanatory and clear.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what is needed. For some reason it is lacking from the documentation for both [SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.userpreferencechanged) and [UserPreferenceChangedEventArgs Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.userpreferencechangedeventargs). Fortunately you persisted and found it in the doc for [UserPreferenceCategory Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.userpreferencecategory)