# Window application freeze randomly

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am facing random freeze issues in my Windows application. On profiling I have found the primary thread stacktrace but not able find my code due to which it happens. I have seen many thread on SO but not able find any appropriate solution.

Here's the snapshot of stacktrace extraced from profiler

[image: Call Stack extracted from Profiler]

Can any point me in the right direction to find the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077822/net-4-0-and-the-dreaded-onuserpreferencechanged-hang)? It seems related based on the `OnUserPreferenceChanged` event that is being raised...

Comment: Ok I will have a look