# Windows application hang at OnUserPreferenceChanged event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am facing random hang issues in my VB.Net Windows application. On profiling I found the OnUserPreferenceChanged in stack trace. In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4078528/3085520) on SO there is workaround provided but I don't understand how to use it in my VB.Net application. Please note Application framework is enabled in my VB.Net application.

Can any one help to understand how to subscribe to this event in VB.Net winform application?

> Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += delegate { };

Comment: That would be something like `AddHandler Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged, Sub() <new line> End Sub`, however I don't think that'll really solve anything.

Comment: Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
            AddHandler Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged, AddressOf PreferenceChangedHandler
        End Sub Tried this in ApplicationEvents.vb file. Is it going to work there?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't. `AddHandler` works anywhere. :)

Comment: Note that Hans just did a major revision of his answer and, in the process, removed the recommended workaround.

Comment: @Craig Thanks for the information. After 7 years Hans edited the answer and removed the provided workaround. Just before I am trying to use the workaround. Still I will go with the workaround for now as I don't have enough time for a proper code cleanup.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thanks for your help. It worked for me. For verifying I have set a message box to appear on this event and it worked successfully without any hang issue. Now suppressed that message box for actual release build.